# Knockout Custom Binding for jQuery .is(':checked') or $(..).prop('checked')

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

In Dom I have a toggle input type checkbox switch, where it can be switched on or off. 
I am using knockout to databind to bind its checked to knockout model. But it is showing as undefined while debugging.

My Dom HTML is,

```
<div class="make-switch switch-large">
    <input type="checkbox" checked class="toggle" data-bind="checked: myvar" />
</div>
```

The data-bind for checked is undefined and not working, because the DOM HTML template I am using looks like a switch. And the value checked is undefined, rather its value is storing in .is(':checked') or $(..).prop('checked')

I am not sure how to bind this using knokcout!

So I tried to implement a custom binding,

```
 ko.bindingHandlers.isChecked = {
            init: function (element) {
                debugger;
                return ($(element).is(':checked'));
            },
            update: function (element) {
                debugger;
                return ($(element).is(':checked'));
            }
        };
```

But this is not updating model, any quick ideas will be much appreciated

Comment: can you post more code?

Comment: I think you should try to get standard ko "checked" binding working for your code. No need to write custom binding instead of existing and then fix it. Could you provide some code from app?

Comment: Guys, I added some DOM HTML and knckout binding. BTW the knockout bindings are working fine with rest of DOM elements